# How to get all the innerHTML from a website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension using which i want know if given word is present in website or not. I have tried using document.documentElement.innerHTML but it is only matching with only some words present at the top of website and giving false result even word is present in that website.

Comment: You need to show an [MCVE](/help/mcve) or a link to that site. Either code is incorrect or the site is using iframe.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

To quote the MDN docs:

> The textContent property of the Node interface represents the text content of the node and its descendants.

Which means you could get the `textContent` of the `body` node and check if it includes the word you want.

```js
const b = document.body;
if (b.textContent.includes('foo bar')) {
  //... it includes 'foo bar'
}
```

This probably isn't the fastest way to approach this although it is very readable and specifying a Node nested deeper inside of body should increase performance.